# Lottie animation strange error on Android, works on iOS. The Path cannot loop back on itself

Tags: android, animation, after-effects, lottie

Someone made this Lottie animation for me: https://lottiefiles.com/share/DO3Kpo

It seems to work perfectly on iOS, but on Android it throws the following Exception. We tried a lot but we can't figure out what the problem could be. Anyone any thoughts about it?

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition ---> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Path cannot loop back on itself.
  at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Path cannot loop back on itself.
  at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.initPath(PathInterpolator.java:185)
  at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.initCubic(PathInterpolator.java:158)
  at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.<init>(PathInterpolator.java:89)
  at at android.support.v4.view.animation.PathInterpolatorCompat.create(PathInterpolatorCompat.java:82)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.KeyframeParser.parseKeyframe(KeyframeParser.java:130)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.KeyframeParser.parse(KeyframeParser.java:58)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.PathKeyframeParser.parse(PathKeyframeParser.java:21)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.AnimatablePathValueParser.parse(AnimatablePathValueParser.java:29)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.AnimatablePathValueParser.parseSplitPath(AnimatablePathValueParser.java:55)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.AnimatableTransformParser.parse(AnimatableTransformParser.java:54)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LayerParser.parse(LayerParser.java:99)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LottieCompositionParser.parseAssets(LottieCompositionParser.java:147)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LottieCompositionParser.parse(LottieCompositionParser.java:77)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSyncInternal(LottieCompositionFactory.java:248)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:242)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:177)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:171)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromAssetSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:114)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$2.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:95)
  at at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$2.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:93)
  at at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can open an issue at https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues

Share the link to the json and they may investigate the issue.

I could reproduce it here. It is happening on Android only because the Exception is happening in a Android class:

```
// Note the class path: android.view.animation.PathInterpolator
at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.initPath(PathInterpolator.java:185)
at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.initCubic(PathInterpolator.java:158)
at at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.<init>(PathInterpolator.java:89)
at at android.support.v4.view.animation.PathInterpolatorCompat.create(PathInterpolatorCompat.java:82)
at at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.KeyframeParser.parseKeyframe(KeyframeParser.java:130)
```

Checking the source code of `PathInterpolator`:

```
float fraction = pointComponents[componentIndex++];
float x = pointComponents[componentIndex++];
float y = pointComponents[componentIndex++];
if (fraction == prevFraction && x != prevX) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The Path cannot have discontinuity in the X axis.");
}
if (x < prevX) {
    // Exception is being triggered here due to x < prevX
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Path cannot loop back on itself.");
}
```

`PathInterpolator` is being invoked by the Lottie library. So, they may provide a better feedback on this issue.

Try there: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues

Note that they need the AEP file. So, talk to your friend in order to get that file:

> Zip your After Effects AEP file and attach it. Your issue will be auto-closed if it doesn't have an AEP or no explicit reason otherwise is given.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging i figured out the problem. There where two layers with the same name, they caused a conflict. Not sure if this is a bug in Lottie for Android, the initial version is working perfectly in iOS. So make sure every layer has a different name ;-)